# Account Linking Actions On Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, fulfillment

After Sign is done, my output for "Get Signin" intent is not displayed.
Using Google-Sign in

```js
app.intent("redeem", (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn("To redeem "));
})

app.intent("Get Signin", (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    const payload = conv.user.profile.payload;
    conv.ask(`I got your account details ${payload.name} , how would you like to redeem? `)
    conv.ask(new Suggestions(['QR code'], ['code']));
  }
  else {
    conv.close("Please sign in to redeem");
  }
})
```

After a successful sign in I get this message:
[image]

Dialogflow Get Signin (top part):
[image: top part]

Dialogflow Get Signin (bottom part):
[image: bottom part]

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot of what the "Get Signin" Intent looks like in Dialogflow?

Comment: Updated question with intent on dialogflow @Prisoner

Comment: Can you include the top part of the Intent as well? Not just the response section? (The Context, Event, and Sample Phrases sections, in particular)

Comment: I did update it , but everything is empty .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Sign-In completes, it triggers the `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` [Dialogflow event](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/helpers#account_sign-in). So your "Get Signin" Intent needs to have this set in the Event field, with no training phrases.

It might look something like this
[image: Illustration of Event field]

Since you don't have an Event or Training phrases set, that Intent will never be triggered. Instead, when the Sign-in completes, Actions will send the Event, but since there is nothing setup to handle the event in Dialogflow, it will fail to do anything, so it will exit with the error about not responding.